# Extending large C Programming Project - Undefined Reference to Various Functions

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, makefile, configure

I am looking to extend a large C Programming project (http://icecast.org/download/) with some additional features. Although I have general programming experience, this is the first time I'm undertaking anything in C and having some struggles.

I decided that when extending the Icecast project with my own modules, I would first test the modules on my own machine (Centos 6 with Eclipse), once working - my intentions are to integrate the changes into the main Icecast project.

My first integration was that of a logging mechanism, which saves simple messages to a local MySQL database, I have successfully got this working on my machine. I copied the code over into a module in the Icecast project, made sure all of the relevant includes were declare. When trying to compile Icecast with the additional functionality using ./configure, make - I receive the following errors:

```
client.o: In function `logSingleMessage':
/home/hearme/radio/src/client.c:283: undefined reference to `mysql_init'
/home/hearme/radio/src/client.c:297: undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect'
/home/hearme/radio/src/client.c:305: undefined reference to `mysql_query'
/home/hearme/radio/src/client.c:307: undefined reference to `mysql_error'
/home/hearme/radio/src/client.c:308: undefined reference to `mysql_close'
/home/hearme/radio/src/client.c:293: undefined reference to `mysql_error'
/home/hearme/radio/src/client.c:312: undefined reference to `mysql_close'
```

Could anyone explain why this is happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The messages you report are linker errors.  They indicate that your program attempts to call the specified functions, but no implementations of them have been linked to it.  The appropriate library should be added to the link, probably `-lmysqlclient`, but maybe `-lmysqlclient_r`.  How you accomplish that depends a lot on details of your build system.

Comment: I appreciate it's a problem with linking, but how do I go about doing this? It's a Centos 6 system. Do I need to edit the configure file?

Comment: i.e. How would I go about adding the appropriate library to the link?

Comment: @GlennHouseRadioCooper: You probably need to edit `configure.in`. Or you could try setting the environment variable `LDFLAGS=-lmysqlclient` prior to running `configure`.

Comment: I apologise for my ignorance, but I've had a look in the configure.in file and wouldn't know where to start with this?

What entries would I be looking to add?

Comment: @alk - I tried setting the global variable, but that did not work

Comment: What does `echo $LDFLAGS` tell you after you set `LDFLAGS`? @GlennHouseRadioCooper

Comment: echo $LDFLAGS prints: -lmysqlclient

Comment: @GlennHouseRadioCooper, As I said, how you actually add the needed library to the link depends *a lot* on the *details* of your build system.  Not to put too fine a point on it, but if you don't know how to maintain and modify your own project's build system then either you need to learn or you need to chuck it and build one that you can maintain.  The Autoconf manual is [available on-line](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/index.html).  It's useful to know how to use it, but that may be more of a detour than you want to take at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You are forking a project that is built with [GNU Autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system)
It is unfortunate that you have picked on an autotooled project for your first venture in C.
You don't need to learn autools to learn C, and really it is essential to understand building C programs or
and libraries with [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) before you tackle autotooled projects. Autotools
is in essence a makefile generating system that adapts its outputs to its findings about the system it is
working in, in the light of the configurational directions that you provide.

You do need to know about autotools to work on typical Unix/Linux OSS projects using compiled
languages. It is not an easy study but if you're ever to make much headway on `icecast` you're
going to have learn at least the rudiments. [`autoconf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html)
and [`automake`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/) are the principal tools. Googling
the like of "{autoconf|automake}{tutorial|hello world}" will be more helpful than not, but not as
much more helpful as you might expect. An additional driver script called `autoreconf` exists that
can automate the running of `autoconf`, `automake` and the less well known autotools in the correct sequence,
but it doesn't let you off having to read and write the input files of those tools.

I can probably get you past your immediate problem, and that will give you an impression that might, or might not,
persuade you to postpone your fork of `icecast` until you have graduated from smaller challenges. My advice
would be for postponment.

It is extra unfortunate that the autotooling of `icecast` (I have grabbed it) is both sophisticated and dated. Whenever
you run current versions of `autoconf` and `automake` on it they issue warnings caused by some antiquated
autooling in the project. We'll fix these before anything else.

You are adding new functionality to icecast that introduces a build time dependency on `libmysqlclient`.
That means the build needs to find both `libmysqlclient` for linkage and the `mysql` headers that
you compile. For the present purpose I'll assume that `mysql/mysql.h` is the only one you want to mention.

You need to make autotools handle these requirements of your functionality whenever they generate your new `./configure` script
for the project, which will in turn generate all the makefiles. To do this you will have to modify the
relevant input files of `autoconf` and `automake` and then rerun these tools on the project (we'll use `autoreconf` to do that). After that,
you have a `./configure` script that will be good until the next time you need to interfere with construction
of the project.

So to begin with, install the autotools on your development system if in you haven't already. I don't know Centos but
a moment's googling suggests that:

```
yum whatprovides autoconf automake libtool
```

or the like should tell you the packages you need, and that:

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

as root will get you them all in one go.

You must apply the changes I'm going to describe on a pristine `icecast` 2.4.2 source tree as extracted from
the tarball. They will not depend on any of your new source code, and when your new source code is present
and autooled into the package (which is `TODO` for you) they will satisfy its `mysql` dependencies. If you apply them on a source tree where you
have already tinkered with the autotooling then of course all bets are off.

**Preliminaries**

In the pristine source tree, run `autoreconf`, to see what it has to say about the package as you got it.

I get a bunch of warnings:-

1)  `aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'`

...repeatedly, and:

2)

```
configure.in:106: warning: AC_LANG_CONFTEST: no AC_LANG_SOURCE call detected in body
../../lib/autoconf/lang.m4:193: AC_LANG_CONFTEST is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2729: _AC_RUN_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:639: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2748: AC_RUN_IFELSE is expanded from...
m4/xiph_curl.m4:6: XIPH_PATH_CURL is expanded from...
configure.in:106: the top level
```

...repeatedly, and:

3)  `src/avl/Makefile.am:13: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')`

4)  `src/httpp/Makefile.am:12: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')`

5)  `src/net/Makefile.am:13: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')`

6)  `src/thread/Makefile.am:13: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')`

You'd better fix these before going any further, or they'll obscure diagnostics provoked later on by your
own mistakes. The obvious ones first:

1) Rename `configure.in` as `configure.ac`

3)  Edit `src/avl/Makefile.am` and replace `INCLUDES` with `AM_CPPFLAGS`

4)  Edit `src/httpp/Makefile.am` and replace `INCLUDES =` with `AM_CPPFLAGS +=`. *Note the difference*.

5)  As per 3.

6)  As per 3.

Warning 2) is due to a missing pair of square brackets in `m4/xiph_curl.m4`. Edit that
file and replace:

```
    AC_RUN_IFELSE(AC_LANG_SOURCE([
#include <curl/curl.h>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
]),,[curl_ok="no"],[curl_ok="yes"])
```

with:

```
    AC_RUN_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([
#include <curl/curl.h>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
]),,[curl_ok="no"],[curl_ok="yes"]])
```

Now run `autoreconf` again and it should have no complaints. Then run `./configure`,
which should complete successfully, and lastly run `make`, which should also be good.

**The fix**

Now you are ready to make your *own* changes for the `libmysqlclient` dependency.

For demonstration purposes I'll assume that the feature you want to add that
depends on `libmysqlclient` is called "Yoyo", and that you want it to be
an extra rather than essential for someone trying to build `icecast` on their
own system from your package. So you will not want a failure to detect that library or the header file to be
fatal at `./configure` time. I assume you will just want the build to disable Yoyo 
support in that event.

Edit `configure.ac` (formerly `configure.in`). Find the line:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([pwd.h unistd.h grp.h sys/types.h],,,AC_INCLUDES_DEFAULT)
```

and insert after it:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(
    [mysql/mysql.h],[AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_MYSQL_MYSQL_H],[true])],
    [AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_MYSQL_MYSQL_H],[false])]
    [AC_MSG_WARN([Header mysql/mysql.h not found. Yoyo support disabled])])
```

Here, you are inserting an `autoconf` macro that directs the generated `./configure` script to
check whether you have got the necessary header `mysql/mysql.h`, record the result of that check and cause the script to
emit a warning if the header is not found. See [`AC_CHECK_HEADERS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.61/html_node/Generic-Headers.html)

Next, still in `configure.ac`, find the stanza:

```
XIPH_PATH_SPEEX(
    [ XIPH_VAR_APPEND([XIPH_CPPFLAGS],[$SPEEX_CFLAGS])
    XIPH_VAR_PREPEND([XIPH_LIBS],[$SPEEX_LIBS])
    XIPH_VAR_APPEND([XIPH_LDFLAGS],[$SPEEX_LDFLAGS])
    ICECAST_OPTIONAL="$ICECAST_OPTIONAL format_speex.o"
    ],
    [ AC_MSG_WARN([Speex support disabled!])
    ])
```

and after it insert:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB(
    [mysqlclient],[mysql_init],
    [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_LIBMYSQLCLIENT],[1],[Define if you have libmysqlclient])]
        [AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_LIBMYSQLCLIENT],[true])] [MYSQL_LIBS="-lmysqlclient"],
    [AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_LIBMYSQLCLIENT],[false])] 
        [AC_MSG_WARN([libmysqlclient not found. Yoyo support is disabled])])
```

Here, you're inserting an `autoconf` macro that directs `./configure`to check if it can
link a test program that calls the external function `mysql_init` against the library `libmysqlclient`. That's
an authenticating check for the availability of the right library. Again the macro will make `./configure`
record the result and issue a warning if the check fails. And, if the check succeeds, then a variable
`MYSQL_LIBS` will be defined = `-lmysqlclient`. See [AC_CHECK_LIB](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Libraries.html)

Further down, find the line:

```
AC_SUBST(KATE_LIBS)
```

and after it insert:

```
AC_SUBST(MYSQL_LIBS)
```

One of the effects of adding this line is that if you use the expression `@MYSQL_LIBS@`
anywhere in automake's input files then in the makefiles generated from them the
expression will be replaced by the value, if any, that is assigned to `MYSQL_LIBS` when
`autoconf` processes `configure.ac`. That value will be `-lmysqlclient` if the library is available
and otherwise nothing. See [AC_SUBST](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html)

The final stage is to make use of that last fact. I will assume that Yoyo requires `libmysqlclient`
just to be linked with the `icecast` executable. If it should be linked with any other targets
of the icecast build, or a yet-to-exist Yoyo target, you can achieve that in much the same way that you'll see now.

In each subdirectory where some target is built you'll find a `Makefile.am`. This file is the schema that
ultimately controls how the target gets built on any system where the package lands, guided by the
local findings and preferences that are baked by `./configure`. You can research the process.

Edit the file `src/Makefile.am`. This is the schema that controls the make of the icecast executable.
Find the line:

```
icecast_LDADD = $(icecast_DEPENDENCIES) @XIPH_LIBS@ @KATE_LIBS@
```

This line schematically specifies the *additional linker flags* (`_LDADD`) of the `icecast` program. Change
this line to:

```
icecast_LDADD = $(icecast_DEPENDENCIES) @XIPH_LIBS@ @KATE_LIBS@ @MYSQL_LIBS@
```

That's all, for the purpose of your immediate problem.

**Check it out**

Now run `autoreconf` again and (if no mistakes have crept in) it will generate a `./configure`
script that is able to adapt your `icecast` build automatically to the availability of `mysqlclient` dev support,
or the lack therefore.

To observe the effect. Run `make clean` to get back to scratch. Temporarily uninstall
`libmysqlclient` and its headers (or temporarily hide them, e.g. by renaming).
Then run `./configure`. It will succeed but the output will include the
warnings:

```
configure: WARNING: Header mysql/mysql.h not found. Yoyo support disabled
configure: WARNING: libmysqlclient not found. Yoyo support is disabled
```

Then run `make`. It succeeds and the build is the same as last time.

Now reinstall `libmysqlclient` and its headers. Run:

```
make clean
./configure
```

`./configure` succeeds but now the `Yoyo support disabled` warnings are gone.

Open the file `src/Makefile` (not `src/Makefile.in` or `src/Makefile.am`). This
is the generated makefile for the `icecast` executable. Search for `MYSQL_LIBS` 
and you find the setting:

```
MYSQL_LIBS = -lmysqlclient
```

Then search for `icecast_LDADD` and you find that its setting contains `-lmysqlclient`

Run `make | grep '\-lmysqlclient'`. The build succeeds ands you see that `libmysqlclient`
is linked in the `icecast` executable. You're not doing anything with it yet, but
it will be there when you need it.

I said that the `AC_CHECK...` macros that you've inserted in `configure.ac` will
make the `configure` script record the results. They record those results in two ways
that you can use to conditionally integrate the Yoyo feature, dependent on the
availability of `mysql` support.

One of those ways is provided by the `AM_CONDITIONAL`s that we used, e.g.

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(
    [mysql/mysql.h], # <-- Header to look for
    [AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_MYSQL_MYSQL_H],[true])], #<-- Do this if found
    # Else do this all...
    [AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_MYSQL_MYSQL_H],[false])]
    [AC_MSG_WARN([Header mysql/mysql.h not found. Yoyo support disabled])])
```

The effect of the `AM_CONDITIONAL`s is to let you write `automake` conditionals
in any of the `Makefile.am`s that define your target builds, e.g you
edit `src/Makefile.am` and insert the like of:

```
if HAVE_LIBMYSQLCLIENT
# ... Do this if libmysqlclient is available
endif
```

and of course there's an `else...endif` variant. When `./configure` generates
a final makefile from this, it will include the stuff that's in the scope of
true conditions and omit the rest.

This form of check-result-recording lets you communicate the results to `make`.
The other way lets you communicate the results directly to your *compiler*.

After you've run `./configure` you'll find there is a top-level header file in
the package tree called `config.h`. Open this and at the top it will tell you
how it came to exist:

```
/* config.h.  Generated from config.h.in by configure.  */
/* config.h.in.  Generated from configure.ac by autoheader.  */
```

The last time you generated this file you had `mysqlclient` dev support installed.
Search in the file for `HAVE_MYSQL_MYSQL_H` and you find:

```
/* Define to 1 if you have the <mysql/mysql.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_MYSQL_MYSQL_H 1
```

Search for `HAVE_LIBMYSQLCLIENT` and you find

```
/* Define if you have libmysqlclient */
#define HAVE_LIBMYSQLCLIENT 1
```

You can rely on it that these these macros will be defined in `config.h` with a
non-zero value if and only if the checks that they represent were successful at
`./configure` time. You can also rely on it that the commandline preprocessor
option `-DHAVE_CONFIG_H` will automatically be passed to all the compiler commands
in the `make` along with `-I` (include-search path) options that will enable the
compiler to locate `config.h`. Hence in any of your C source files you can
write:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include <config.h>
#endif
```

and then in the body of the source file you can access and use the preprocessor
macros that represent the `./configure`-time check results, e.g.

```
#if HAVE_MYSQL_MYSQL_H
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#endif
```

**Finally**

Here I have *not* sketched the proper was to integrate Yoyo optionally in `icecast`.
I've just sketched an approach you can take to produce `icecast-with-yoyo` *if the
dependencies of Yoyo are satisfied* and otherwise produce `icecast` classic,
so you still have autotooling that isn't *broken*. But it would be rated as rude and amateurish autotooling.

The proper way to provide Yoyo as an optional feature is to equip the
`./configure` script with a commandline parameter `--enable-yoyo`
and to document it in `./configure --help`, so that the installer of the
package and choose whether to build Yoyo support or not. Then if I run `./configure` without
`--enable-yoyo`, yoyo support will not be built. But if I do specify that
option then `./configure` should *fail* if Yoyo's dependencies are not satisfied.
Instead of `AC_MESSAGE_WARN`, you'd be using [`AC_MESSAGE_ERROR`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Printing-Messages.html),
and your `configure.ac` would become more elaborate. If and when you ever want to investigate how to implement such a `./configure`
parameter you can start at [AC_ARG_ENABLE](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.66/html_node/Package-Options.html)

Comment: Wow, that was very useful. As suspected, I feel like I am out of my depth and before I continue, more research is required.

I appreciate that the makefile is required to make the program portable, but because I am solely using this program in a Centos environment, I am wondering whether it would be easier for myself to write my own gcc script to compile the program purely for my Centos system?

I am going to spend some time analysing your comments above. My project extends on Icecast quite a bit and involves a number of libraries, it is essential that I understand what I'm doing

Comment: I think it would be an amply ambitious plan to work up a purely `make`-based build of icecast, no autotools, that works on your own
system for developing your new features and also learning about `make`, which is a large enough study itself and a fundamental for C work on Linux - unlike autotools. Don't avoid `make` in favour of an entirely hand-rolled script. That's pointless. `make` doesn't hide anything you ought to know: it *is* what you ought to know.

Comment: I've been reading through various documents (searches led by your recommended reading above) and believe you are correct @Mike. I'll report back in a day or so when I've digested some reading, and no doubt will have some questions or clarifications, many thanks again for your time

Comment: Ok, I've done a bit of reading and tried to implement above. <Preliminaries> No warnings - so did not implement any of the fixes. <The Fix> Implemented everything here, but still receiving the same errors, this time ./configure is returning:  `WARNING: libmysqlclient not found. Yoyo support is disabled` There obviously seems to be an error finding the header file. Running the program in Eclipse I had to set the following flags to get it working: `I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -include/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h` and .... `-L/usr/lib64/mysql/`

Comment: Apologies, there are more flags to the above. This is a successful gcc script on the same machine where I've integrated the mysql - `gcc -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -include/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h -o Test1 DBLogger.c main.c NetworkRequest.c -L/usr/lib64/mysql/ -lmysqlclient -lcurl -lz `

Comment: Does it link without the `-L/usr/lib64/mysql/`?

Comment: It doesn't @Mike Kinghan `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient`

Comment: In that case *The fix* is functioning correctly. `libmysqlclient` does not
exist in the linker's standard search directories on your system. If it did,
you would not need to specify any `-L` option for the linker to find it.
You can see your linker's standard search directories by passing `-v` (verbose) to `gcc` and looking for the `LIBRARY_PATH` line in the output. To make the fixed `./configure` get over this on your system your can run `./configure LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64/mysql/

Comment: Thanks @Mike, that worked absolutely fine `./configure LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64/mysql/` You've been a great help